# wxPython formatting questions

Tags: python, wxpython

I have an app I was working on to learn more about wxPython( I have been primarily been a scripter ). I forgot about it now I am opening it back up. It's a screen scraper, and I have it working almost the way I want it, going to build a regex parser to strip out the links in every scrape that I don't need. The questions I have are this. In it current state, if I check more than one site, it goes out and scrapes, and returns it in separate windows, the for:each section in the Clicked function. I want to put them in a frame, in the window, altogether. I also want to know if I can take the list they are read into and send it to a checklist, so someone could check off separate items, I want to build a save function and keep certain ones. In regards to a save function, I want to keep saved checks, are there calls to the widgets to save their states? I know it's a lot, but thanks for the help.

**EDIT** (forgot code)

```
import wx
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import Tag
import re
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, originalTextFor, SkipTo, Combine
import wx
import wx.html
global P

siteDict = {0:'http://www.reddit.com', 1:'http://www.boston.com', 2:'http://www.stumbleupon.com', 3:'news.google.com'}

class citPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        allSites = ['Reddit', 'Boston.com', 'StumbleUpon', 'Google News']
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Choose the Sites you would like Charlie to Visit:", (45, 15))      
        self.sitList = wx.CheckListBox(self, 20, (60, 50), wx.DefaultSize, allSites)

class nextButton(wx.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, label, pos):
        wx.Button.__init__(self, parent, id, label, pos)

class checkList(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(400, 300))
        self.panel = citPanel(self, -1)
        nextButton(self.panel, 30, 'Ok', (275, 50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Clicked)       
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def Clicked(self, event):
        checkedItems = [i for i in range(self.panel.sitList.GetCount()) if self.panel.sitList.IsChecked(i)]
        print checkedItems
        r = [siteDict[k] for k in checkedItems]
        print r
        for each in r:
            pre = '<HTML><head><title>Page title</title></head>'
            post = '</HTML>'
            site = urllib2.urlopen(each)
            html=site.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
            tags = soup.findAll('a')

            soup1 = BeautifulSoup(''.join(str(t) for t in tags))

            for link in soup1.findAll('a'):
                br= Tag(soup, 'p')
                index= link.parent.contents.index(link)
                link.parent.insert(index+1, br)

            P = soup1.prettify()
            print P

        #for link2 in soup1.findAll('a'):
            #p1= Tag(soup, '

            frm = MyHtmlFrame(None, "Charlie", P)
            frm.Show()




class MyHtmlFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, page):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self)
        if "gtk2" in wx.PlatformInfo:
            html.SetStandardFonts()

        html.SetPage(page)


        #app = wx.PySimpleApp()

        #app.MainLoop()


    #event.Skip()




    #self.Destroy()



app = wx.App()



checkList(None, -1, 'Charlie')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single answer panel or frame (start with a separate frame, like you are doing now - MyHtmlFrame is fine). Don't create a new panel or frame for every result.

Create a `wx.ComboBox(self, -1, choices=['google','so']) somewhere, and bind self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, myHtmlFrame.setFrame).

Now you need to write MyHtmlFrame.setFrame(self,event); use `choice = event.GetSelection()`, then `self.html.SetPage(self.results_dict[choice])`

Oh, and attach a dictionary (`results_dict`) on MyHtmlFrame, mapping the choice (`"google"`) to the scraper result.

Unless you want the combo-box in a separate frame, you'll have to learn how to use wx.Sizers.

```
class MyHtmlFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, page, results_dict):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        self.html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self)
        if "gtk2" in wx.PlatformInfo:
            self.html.SetStandardFonts()
        self.results_dict=results_dict #here

        self.html.SetPage('')

    def setFrame(self,event):
        self.html.SetPage(self.results_dict[choice])
```

Comment: I am really sorry this is so long after you answered, but, I had a lot at the end of the month. I was playing around with this, and I had a few questions. The dict, are you saying take every link it returns, and put it in a dictionary with the key being the site it came from? Is that the only way to get them to show in the same window? Also, I was interested in having the html frame being part of the same frame as the check box, so would it be initialized empty, and populated after?

Comment: I'm saying that you don't need a new frame for every result. You can just set the contents of one frame depending on which page you want to view. Of course, you can use wx.Notebook (or choicebook, or listbook or wxTreebook ) to select between multiple panels ala Firefox tabs. Also, look at wx sizers for putting several widgets in the same frame. But get one thing (either layout or tabs) working before you try the other.